# SLE: installing certbot and its NGINX plugin

Tags: opensuse, suse, letsencrypt, certbot

#### openSUSE Tumbleweed

Installing [`certbot`](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=certbot&project=home%3Aecsos%3Aserver) and its NGINX plugin on openSUSE Tumbleweed was just straightforward:

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ecsos:server/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/home:ecsos:server.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install certbot
```

Then, install `python36-certbot-nginx` and finally run:

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

#### SLE 15 SP2

But I'm trying to do the same on SLE 15 SP2. I tried:

- openSUSE backports repo
- openSUSE Leap 15.2 repos
- Instructions [here](https://en.opensuse.org/Let%E2%80%99s_Encrypt)
- Couldn't figure out how to use [this](https://packagehub.suse.com/packages/certbot/) by command-line
- ...

What am I missing? Is there a convenient way to install `certbot` and its NGINX plugin by the command line on SLE 15 SP2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands installed the `certbot` on SLE 15 SP2:

```
sudo SUSEConnect -p PackageHub/15.2/x86_64
sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper install python3-certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

And then, this command enabled HTTPS for all the servers handled by NGINX:

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Problem solved =)

##### Note

Don't forget to automate renewal by this:

https://certbot.org/renewal-setup